# How to set Parquet file encoding in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

Parquet documentation describe few different encodings [here](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-format/blob/master/Encodings.md)

Is it changes somehow inside file during read/write, or I can set it?
Nothing about it in Spark documentation. Only found [slides](https://www.slideshare.net/RyanBlue3/parquet-performance-tuning-the-missing-guide) from speach by Ryan Blue from Netflix team. He sets parquet configurations to sqlContext

```
sqlContext.setConf("parquet.filter.dictionary.enabled", "true")
```

Looks like it's not about plain dictionary encoding in Parquet files.

Comment: Spark provides predefined methods to read/write parquet files if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: How can I set encoding during write? f.e. dataFrame.write().parquet(<no ars about encoding>)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I found an answer to my question on twitter engineering [blog](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us.html).

Parquet has an automatic dictionary encoding enabled when a number of unique values < 10^5.
[Here](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/announcing-parquet-10-columnar-storage-for-hadoop.html) is a post announcing Parquet 1.0 with self-tuning dictionary encoding

**UPD:**

Dictionary encoding can be switched in SparkSession configs:

```
SparkSession.builder
            .appName("name")
            .config("parquet.enable.dictionary","false") //true
```

Regarding encoding by column, there is an open [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1058) as improvement in Parquet’s Jira that was created on 14th July, 17. Since dictionary encoding is a default and works only for all table it turns off Delta Encoding(Jira [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-796) for this bug) which is the only suitable encoding for data like timestamps where almost each value is unique.

**UPD2**

How can we tell which encoding was used for an output file?

- I used parquet-tools for it.

  -> brew install parquet-tools (for mac)
  -> parquet-tools meta *your_parquet_file*.snappy.parquet

Output:

```
.column_1: BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:16637 SZ:2912/8114/3.01 VC:26320 ENC:RLE,PLAIN_DICTIONARY,BIT_PACKED
.column_2: BINARY SNAPPY DO:0 FPO:25526 SZ:119245/711487/1.32 VC:26900 ENC:PLAIN,RLE,BIT_PACKED
.
```

Where PLAIN and PLAIN_DICTIONARY are encodings which were used for that columns

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Artem's answer, parquet-tools has been marked as deprecated and can no longer be installed via homebrew. An alternative way of running this tool is to use an older branch from parquet-mr

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr.git
git checkout tags/apache-parquet-1.8.1
cd parquet-mr/parquet-tools
mvn clean package -Plocal
java -jar target/parquet-tools-1.8.1.jar meta <your_parquet_file.snappy.parquet>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether I've understood the entire scope of your query (and in that case, please feel free to clarify).

You can specify storage options for a hive table using "CREATE TABLE src(id int) USING hive OPTIONS(fileFormat 'parquet')"
[reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#specifying-storage-format-for-hive-tables)

[This one should be easier to follow and more comprehensive](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files)

Read/ Write file:
val usersDF = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/users.parquet")
usersDF.select("name", "favorite_color").write.save("namesAndFavColors.parquet")

I'm also assuming you might have already checked:
- sqlContext.parquetFile("File_to_be_read.parquet")
- myDataFrame.saveAsParquetFile("file_to_be_saved.parquet")

Comment: OP knows how to create a parquet files, but there are multiple possible encodings for a parquet file in the spec and want to know if this is configurable in spark.