# pyspark writes Parquet files with different encoding

Tags: pyspark, parquet

When using pyspark to write parquet files, is there a way to set the encoding? It looks like the default is "Dictionary Encoding (PLAIN_DICTIONARY = 2 and RLE_DICTIONARY = 8)"

- Plain: (PLAIN = 0)
- Dictionary Encoding (PLAIN_DICTIONARY = 2 and RLE_DICTIONARY = 8)
- Run Length Encoding / Bit-Packing Hybrid (RLE = 3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set Parquet file encoding in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488227/how-to-set-parquet-file-encoding-in-spark)