# Spark : Japanese letters are garbled in Paquet files created in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, character-encoding, parquet, spark-csv

I have a Spark job which reads some CSV file on S3 ,process and save the result as parquet files.These CSV contains Japanese text.

When I run this job on local, reading the S3 CSV file and write to parquet files into local folder, the japanese letters looks fine.

But when I ran this on my spark cluster, reading the same S3 CSV file and write parquet to HDFS , all the Japanese letters are garbled.

**run on spark-cluster (data is garbled)**

```
spark-submit --master spark://spark-master-stg:7077 \
--conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Ddatabase=dev_mall -Dtable=table_base_TEST -DtimestampColumn=time_stamp -DpartitionColumns= -Dyear=-1 -Dmonth=-1 -DcolRenameMap=  -DpartitionByYearMonth=true -DaddSpdbCols=false -DconvertTimeDateCols=true -Ds3AccessKey=xxxxx -Ds3SecretKey=yyyy -Ds3BasePath=s3a://bucket/export/e2e-test -Ds3Endpoint=http://s3.url -DhdfsBasePath=hdfs://nameservice1/tmp/encoding-test -DaddSpdbCols=false" \
--name Teradata_export_test_ash \
--class com.mycompany.data.spark.job.TeradataNormalTableJob \
--deploy-mode client \
https://artifactory.maven-it.com/spdb-mvn-release/com.mycompany.data/teradata-spark_2.11/0.1/teradata-spark_2.11-0.1-assembly.jar
```

**run locally (data looks fine)**

```
spark-submit --master local \
--conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC \
--conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Ddatabase=dev_mall -Dtable=table_base_TEST -DtimestampColumn=time_stamp -DpartitionColumns= -Dyear=-1 -Dmonth=-1 -DcolRenameMap=  -DpartitionByYearMonth=true -DaddSpdbCols=false -DconvertTimeDateCols=true -Ds3AccessKey=xxxxx -Ds3SecretKey=yyyy -Ds3BasePath=s3a://bucket/export/e2e-test -Ds3Endpoint=http://s3.url -DhdfsBasePath=/tmp/encoding-test -DaddSpdbCols=false" \
--name Teradata_export_test_ash \
--class com.mycompany.data.spark.job.TeradataNormalTableJob \
--deploy-mode client \
https://artifactory.maven-it.com/spdb-mvn-release/com.mycompany.data/teradata-spark_2.11/0.1/teradata-spark_2.11-0.1-assembly.jar
```

As can be seen above, both spark-submit jobs points to the same S3 file, only different is when running on Spark cluster, the result is written to HDFS.

Reading CSV:

```
def readTeradataCSV(schema: StructType, path: String) : DataFrame = {
        dataFrameReader.option("delimiter", "\u0001")
          .option("header", "false")
          .option("inferSchema", "false")
          .option("multiLine","true")
          .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
          .option("charset", "UTF-8")
          .schema(schema)
          .csv(path)

     }
```

This is how I write to parquet:

```
finalDf.write
      .format("parquet")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .option("path", hdfsTablePath)
      .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
      .option("charset", "UTF-8")
      .partitionBy(parCols: _*)
      .save()
```

This is how data on HDFS looks like:
[image]

Any tips on how to fix this ?

Does the input CSV file has to be in UTF-8 encoding ?

** **Update** **
Found out its not related to Parquet, rather CSV loading. Asked a seperate question here :

[Spark CSV reader : garbled Japanese text and handling multilines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868668/spark-csv-reader-garbled-japanese-text-and-handling-multilines)

Comment: Hadoop libraries assume UTF-8 encoding by default. But pure Java libraries rely on `file.encoding` system property by default -- that property depends on OS settings and hard-coded settings (and can be overriden only as a command-line parameter, before the JVM has started).

Comment: Anyway, from Spark source code (V3.0 ) for `CSVOptions` https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/csv/CSVOptions.scala the default encoding for CSV is UTF-8 but it can be overriden by either "encoding" or "charset" _(they are synonyms)_ `val charset = parameters.getOrElse("encoding", parameters.getOrElse("charset", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()))`

Comment: thank you, but we use Spark 2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

Parquet format has no option for `encoding` or `charset` cf. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetOptions.scala

Hence your code has no effect:

```
finalDf.write
      .format("parquet")
      .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
      .option("charset", "UTF-8")
(...)
```

These options apply only for CSV, you should set them *(or rather ONE of them since they are synonyms)* when **reading** the source file.
Assuming you are using the Spark dataframe API to read the CSV; otherwise you are on your own.

Comment: Recommended read about how Parquet manages "compression" of Strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488227/how-to-set-parquet-file-encoding-in-spark

Comment: I tried reading the same S3 file using "spark.sparkContext.textFile(path)" and encoding works fine ! not sure whats happening inside the CSV Plugin

Comment: seems the issue was not related to Parquet rather CSV loading. I asked a separate question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61868668/spark-csv-reader-garbled-japanese-text-and-handling-multilines